Passing Exception type and type hinting
I have the following python code:
from pathlib import Path

def ffind_overview_ex(base_dir: Path, exc: Exception = FileNotFoundError) -> Path:
    try:
        # do something

    except Exception as err:
        raise exc("hello") from err

    ## do some more
    if some_extraordinary_condition:
        raise exc("Wow, it really happened!?")

    return result   # result is of type Path

test = foo(SystemExit)

The code works pretty fine, however MyPy is angry with that code:
lib\cnmerge\merger.py:53: error: Incompatible default for argument "exc" (default has type "type[FileNotFoundError]", argument has type "Exception")  [assignment]
lib\cnmerge\merger.py:59: error: "Exception" not callable  [operator]
lib\cnmerge\merger.py:62: error: "Exception" not callable  [operator]
lib\cnmerge\merger.py:67: error: "Exception" not callable  [operator]
test.py:96: error: Argument 2 to "ffind_overview_ex" has incompatible type "type[SystemExit]"; expected "Exception"  [arg-type]
Found 5 errors in 2 files (checked 1 source file)

My intention is that to control what type of Exception ffind_overview_ex() are throwing, rather than creating either a complex except block to handle the myriad exceptions ffind_overview_ex() could throw, or create a sink exception handler.
So, while the code works, what to do with MyPy? How can I "appease" it? AFAIK both FileNotFoundError and SystemExit are inherited from Exception.

exc: Exception -> exc: type[Exception]. You are passing in an exception class, not an exception instance. To put it another way, a: int = 1 assigns an instance of int (here 1) to a, not the class int; a: int = int would result in the same kind of mypy errors.

This question is similar to: How to annotate a type that's a class object (instead of a class instance)?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The purpose of different exception types is to distinguish between different kinds of errors. How is the caller of the function supposed to know what exception is appropriate? You seem to be treating the exception type as an exception handler. You should be explicit and pass a handler (which itself might raise an exception) for ffind_overview_ex to call.

In addition to @dROOOze's comment re. adding type, you must also change Exception to BaseException since SystemExit does not inherit from Exception.
MyPy Playground
